# swift auto-abbreviates my NSURL with " ... " over the characters it can't fit?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

So I've built up a long string with a path that I want to write a file to, such as:

```
/Users/<mylongusername>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF7BF515-BFC9-4900-BBF4-E70268EDCD59/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE6698CD-98D4-4DEA-8C01-CE70029D922B/Documents/looks/2052f438-5a75-11e6-914c-06bcb4e621d1.mp4
```

This is 226 characters long.

When I create an NSURL out of this with the line :

```
locationURL = NSURL(string: filePath)!
```

it gets set to a much shorter string:

```
/Users/<mylongusername>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF7BF515-BFC9-4900-BBF4-E70268EDCD59/data/Containers/Data ... 21d1.mp4
```

Complete with spaces and all, which can't exist in a URL, and hence that URL can't be used to later retrieve the file.  Why is this happening, can't NSURL handle up to 255 characters?  Am I too close to the limit?  Would using a different URL constructor help, like fileURLWithPath?

Comment: "it gets set to a much shorter string" How do you know? You must be printing it out to string somehow (e.g. in the console) so how do you know this isn't just some sort of figment of the way it's printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For above problem instead of the `locationURL = NSURL(string: filePath)` you can use the `locationURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)`

```
   let filePath = "/Users/<mylongusername>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF7BF515-BFC9-4900-BBF4-E70268EDCD59/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE6698CD-98D4-4DEA-8C01-CE70029D922B/Documents/looks/2052f438-5a75-11e6-914c-06bcb4e621d1.mp4"
   let locationURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
   print("the url = \(locationURL)")
```